# Destroy previous page (NavigationService.GoBack()) in WPF Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm new to developing windows phone 8 application, In that first page is `UserRegistration.xaml`. After completion of user registration process it goes to `MessageList.xaml` page, It's fine but when press back button of windows phone it goes back to the `UserRegistration.xaml` that I don't want.I want to close the application after clicking on back button but the application keeps the previous page in stack for navigation( `NavigationService.GoBack();`). So how can I exit the application from `MessageList.xaml` page or how can I collapse the  previous page activity?

Comment: Please note that Windows Phone is not the same as WPF; please consider removing the tag and the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something similar to this in MessageList.xaml.cs

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (NavigationService.CanGoBack) { NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry(); }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but no need to call the base (it doesn't do anything).